# Obtaining username from user id | discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Well I have been working with databases for a while with discord in order to obtain major lists of user id's in a queue, although I am having problem's obtaining the user from user id as it returns none

For Example

---

```
members = list(privateduos[matchid])
user = discord.User(id=int(members[0]))
await client.say("Say `test` " + str(user))
await client.wait_for_message(content="test", author=user)
```

This is the Output

[image: Output:]

The *client.wait_for_message* doesnt seem to detect the message author in the code as well, any solutions?

Comment: What version of discord.py are you using? In the async branch, al ids are strings.  You should be using [`Client.get_user_info`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user_info) to get the user objects over creating a `User` manually.

Comment: i have been using 0.16.12(if i am not wrong)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method client.get_user_info is deprecated since the last Migration, you should use Client.fetch_user() instead

See this link for the details : https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html

Comment: im well aware about the rewrite documentation now, this question is over 2 year old and I no longer require answers for it. Marking this as the best solution for future viewers of this question,thank you anyway

Answer (score 2):

Use `await client.get_user_info(members[0])`

From there on, (assuming that you have allocated the returned value to `user`) you can do `user.name` to obtain the username.
(Or fetch other information about the `user` as stated [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User).)

Comment: used this ... `user = await client.fetch_user(id)`