# Discord.py How would I retrieve the NICKNAME of someone in the server when having their ID?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How would I retrieve the NICKNAME of someone in the server when having their ID?
Pretty straight forward question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Obtaining username from user id | discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53672754/obtaining-username-from-user-id-discord-py)