# Discord.py: How do I get the user name from the user ID

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Yeah, so I got the user ID of the Users, but I'm unable to find code to get the user name, like I tried everything like `client.fetch_user(payload.user_id)` and `client.get_user(user_id)` but it won't work.

Here is the code:

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def test(ctx,id):
  print(getname(id))

def getname(a):
  return client.get_user(a).name
```

thanks.

Comment: When you say you tried everything, what are some examples of what you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Obtaining username from user id | discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53672754/obtaining-username-from-user-id-discord-py)

Comment: no, that doesn't work for me...

Comment: what is the error when u use `client.fetch_user(payload.user_id)`

Comment: name 'payload' is not defined

Comment: Are you performing an API call or this just general usage?

Comment: what is an API call?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to have have it in a different function then you can do:

```py
async def getname(ctx):
    user = await ctx.author.guild.fetch_member(id)
    return user
```

If you're trying to get the name specifically try adding `.name` behind `ctx.author.guild.fetch_member(id)`

Maybe this is the answer you're looking for?

Comment: Nah, that won't work, it's just an example, I need it to work in a sperat function.