# Trying to get user ID from slash command

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I have a slash command that takes a user as an input

````py
@bot.slash_command(name="tmp", description="testing command")
async def say_hello(ctx):
    with open('data/users.json', 'r') as json_file:
        json_object = json.load(json_file)
        data = json.dumps(json_object, indent=1)
        await ctx.respond(f'Heres your data!\n```json\n{data}```')

@bot.slash_command(name="lookup", desription="Shows all logged data on a given user")
async def lookup(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    await ctx.respond(f'user inputed `{user}`')
````

If I enter myself in the slash command it outputs as `expertnugget#0`, which isn't usable. I wasn't expecting ID but I do need the ID.

Comment: Simply use `user.id`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Obtaining username from user id | discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53672754/obtaining-username-from-user-id-discord-py)

Answer (score 1):

### What is a user ID?

An ID is a unique identifier for a user. It's of type [int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) and it's given to every discord User.

Docs:

> [image: What the id is]

### How do I get this ID?

Because every [discord.User](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.User) ([discord.User](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.User) is global, [discord.Member](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Member) is for every guild) has an ID, if you have the object it's very easy to obtain. In your example:

```py
@bot.slash_command(name="lookup",
                   desription="Shows all logged data on a given user")
async def lookup(ctx, user: discord.Member):
  
  await ctx.respond(f'user inputed `{user.id}`')  # Change this line and add the attribute .id
```

### Sources:

- https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.User
- https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.Member.id

Note: Although the question post may be seen as poorly written, I believe it may be useful in search (quick "lazy" searches get more views). This is because it's not a duplicate and it's more specific. A community edit could fix a lot in the parent post.